# Other open files block connection to 'System' topic for Dynamic Data Exchange with MS Office 365 Excel?

Tags: excel, delphi, office365, dde

I am using TDdeClientConv http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DdeMan_TDdeClientConv.html (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/about-dynamic-data-exchange) to read (selected) Excel data from Delphi 6 application. I use 'Excel' service application name and 'System' topic name. All is fine. But on Windows 10 with MS Office 365 Excel the connection to the 'System' topic fails if other Excel files are open. And hence the `TDdeClientConv.OpenLink` opens empty Excel workbook.

```
FConv := DdeConnect(ddeMgr.DdeInstId, FHszApp, FHszTopic, @Context);
```

does not report error (it returns handle only) and it is API function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ddeml/nf-ddeml-ddeconnect) and I have no means to call GetLastError on it. So - what can be the causes why open Excel files prevent initiation of DDE conversation?

Comment: Why use DDE to interact with Excel?  Using early- or late-bound automation works fine and can do a lot more that DDE.

Comment: DDE died years ago. It is only (barely) supported for backward compatibility purposes by Windows. You should have moved away from DDE at least a decade ago. Don't be surprised if you have difficulties with it.  Office is starting to drop support (or tighten security for using) older technologies as well. (And if `DDEConnect` fails, you can use `DDEGetLastError` to find out why, as the linked page clearly states. Standard `GetLastError` only works when a function is documented to use it on failure, which `DDEConnect` does not.) Automation is supported even in Delphi 6.

Comment: As far as the call to `DDEGetLastError`, you call it just exactly as documented, by calling `DDEGetLastError(ddeMgr.DdeInstId)`. The meaning of the results are documented at MSDN on the page for `DDEGetLastError`, which is linked from the page you linked in your question in the second link.

Comment: DDE is old, but still exists and has been supported in Office for a long time. But in recent years it was abused by malware. Because of that, it's disabled now in Word. Maybe not fully in Excel, but I can imagine they have implemented some security measures there as well. Anyway, DDE was superseded by OLE/COM automation since Office 97. That is 1997, or 22 years ago.

Comment: @GolezTrol Is it OK to use OLE/COM now? After 22 years? As I see the Interop alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002256/excel-interop-alternative then all of them uses OpenDocument Format features but I should support older Excel formats as well. So, I guess, OLE/COM is the most modern and up-to-date interop mechanisms even today, after 22 years and it is fine to use it even now?

Comment: The primary interop assemblies (PIA) are a .NET/managed wrapper around the COM interfaces. Since Delphi doesn't really speak .NET, and the underlying technology is still COM, it doesn't make sense to go that route.

Comment: As for writing files directly (either some open document format, xlsx, or the older xls binary format), that can definitely have advantages, _if_ you want to have a file as output rather than a spreadsheet opened in Excel. There is an SDK for writing office files, or a tonne of 3rd party libraries to choose from. For Delphi, I use [Kluug's OExport](http://www.kluug.net/xlsx-ods-delphi.php), which is great, if you just want simple and fast xls(x) exports without actually requiring Excel.

Comment: Note though, that although the technology hasn't changed much, the actual component model has, and every version introduces new interfaces with new features, so make sure to import the type library for the version(s) you want to support, so you can use all its features.